# "move unassisted"

Tags: grammar, word-formation

As far as I know, "move" is a Verb, "unassisted" is an adjective, and a verb is modified by an adverb. So could you please help me to explain this following sentence, which is from the Oxford dictionary? 
"She could not move unassisted."

Comment: _Unassisted_ modifies _she_, not _move_.

Comment: It's the same as *she could not move without assistance* or *she could not move unless she was being assisted.*